# What does a "sunrise holding you" mean?

Tags: expressions

This is one of the lyrics in "Still Fallin" sung by Hunter Hayes.

The lyrics go,

> "And after every sunrise holding you,
>
> after all the crazy we've been through,
>
> every day and every minute, girl it's something new,
>
> I'm still learning, still burning, still wanting, still all-in, still fallin."

Here, is "And after every sunrise holding you" a metaphor for
'after long time has passed'?

What does a 'sunrise holding you' mean? 
I don't get it.

If anyone's out there to help me, I'd really appreciate it :)
Thanks xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are misunderstanding the meaning.

It (probably) means: *And after every sunrise (when I woke up) holding you* - it's not that the sunrise was doing the holding, but that the holding was done (by the narrator) during the sunrise, indicating they spent the night together.

I say (probably) because it is hard to know what the author meant to communicate. This is how *I* interpret these words.